# How does the body develop an allergy during a lifetime?

Tags: allergy, allergen

I've heard about people who weren't allergic to peanut butter or pollen previously in their lives, but suddenly develop an allergy to that substance. What is the mechanism behind an allergy "suddenly" appearing later in life?

Comment: If possible, can you cite the source?

Comment: Cite the person who I heard developed an allergy? That won't help address the question.

Comment: in that case, can you make describe the person who develop an allergy? Men or women, year to develop, living environment, etc. Just want to make the question clearer, you know

Comment: I cannot because the information came from a health video 5 years ago. It was some kind of taped science show that reenacted a woman's allergies to dog dandruff, bee stings, and dust, narrating the reaction in a biological perspective.

Comment: @Ooker People developing allergies to things they previously did not have an allergy to isn't uncommon so there's no need for the OP to describe such a person.

Comment: Does this exclude hypotheses that adult allergies are simply manifestations of normal allergies that have lain dormant up until this point in the individual's life? I've seen those mentioned in some studies.

Comment: @HDE226868 All answers backed by scientific evidence and reputable sources are welcome.

Comment: I would also like to know why allergy goes at a particular age . For eg I was allergic to shell foods like egg . But after 18 I could eat any number of eggs I want .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MayoClinic, it isn't clear why adult allergies develop:
http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/food-allergy/expert-answers/food-allergy/faq-20058483

However, there is evidence that food sensitivities develop when someone has a compromised gut. If the gut is compromised, undigested food particles "leak" into the blood stream and the body creates antibodies against this undigested food.  These sensitivities can disappear if the gut is repaired.
http://www.holistichelp.net/blog/why-do-food-sensitivities-develop-and-spread/